# Calculate column value and insert another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have create two  tables `deposit` and  `final_balance`;I want to sum `deposit_amount` in `deposit` table and insert the result into `final_balance`  table.
Can I can use a trigger?

```
CREATE TABLE deposit(cust_id VARCHAR2(10),loan_id VARCHAR2(10),deposit_type VARCHAR2(10),deposit_amount NUMBER(20));
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS1','001LOAN1','Fixed',3500);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS2','001LOAN2','Fixed',3900);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS3','001LOAN3','Fixed',7000);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS4','001LOAN4','Fixed',28000);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS5','001LOAN5','Fixed',15200);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS6','001LOAN6','Fixed',2420);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('001CUS7','001LOAN7','Primary',2420);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('002CUS1','002LOAN1','Primary',27000);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('002CUS2','002LOAN2','Primary',20200);
INSERT INTO deposit values ('002CUS3','002LOAN3','Primary',6900);
CREATE TABLE final_balance(
total_deposit NUMBER(20)
);
```

Comment: May be it would be better to create view? Think of it. Every time this 2 columns change you should upgrade table final_balance. I assume you want some report, then view is better solution than table.

Comment: Please post what you tried. Do you need your final_balance table to be automatically updated when you modify data in deposit table? Or do you need to evaluate the result one shot, without handling modifications on deposit table?

Comment: i want to SUM   of total deposit_amount and insert  final balance table in total deposit field # evgeniyK

Comment: ya i need  final_balance table to be automatically updated when i modify data in deposit table, # Evgeniy K

Comment: @brids Answer: Yes you can use trigger. I don't like this solution. I prefer mv or simple view. It also means that smt wrong to your db design if you want create table for single row which is result of simple query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a one-shot evaluation, you can use:

```
SQL> insert into final_balance
  2    select sum(deposit_amount)
  3    from deposit;

1 row created.
```

If you need a self-updating result, a view would be a better solution:

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW v_final_balance(total_deposit) as
  2  select sum(deposit_amount)
  3    from deposit;

View created.
```

In the beginning, they both show the same result:

```
SQL> select * from final_balance;

TOTAL_DEPOSIT
-------------
       116540

SQL> select * from v_final_balance;

TOTAL_DEPOSIT
-------------
       116540
```

After updating data in `deposit` table, the view will show the updated total amount, with no need for triggers:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO deposit
  2       VALUES (
  3               'XX',
  4               'YY',
  5               'ZZ',
  6               1000000000
  7              );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from final_balance;

TOTAL_DEPOSIT
-------------
       116540

SQL> select * from v_final_balance;

TOTAL_DEPOSIT
-------------
   1000116540
```

You could even use a trigger-based approach, but it would need triggers for insert, update, delete, thus resulting in a more complex solution. If you have no specific needs for triggers, I believe the view is the best solution.

Comment: Dear Aleksej it is smart solution thanks  but i can use view table same as normal table? and connect  frontend report ? actually i want to create a project  which all calculation complete are backend. i can use triggering ??

Comment: You can use a view in a select statement exactly as if it was a table.

Comment: i am new student please forgive me my explanation,

Comment: Hello -Aleksej, i am success to create view , now  i can create another view ? using subtract (v_final_balance-final_balance), and i can percentage do operation??  and i can sum,subtract,multiplication a one view ?

Comment: You can create a view the same way you do a select query; whatever you can do in a select ( sum, substract, percentage, ...) you can do in a view

Comment: please give me example if possible (v_final_balance-final_balance) thanks